# Making sure Image is fetched in Jquery click function before moving to new page.

Tags: jquery, html, click, onclick, jquery-callback

I am using jQuery 1.2.6 :(

When a user clicks on Html element with ID=LINKID and having anchor tags, he would be redirected to a new page.
I want to make sure that a small image is fetched before the browser moves to a different page.

Is there any way using callbacks or any other mechanism in jQuery.

```
HTML:
<div id="LINKID"><a href="link location"> </a></div> 


SCRIPT:
jQuery("#LINKID a").click(function(){
var url = "Image location";
(new Image()).src = url;
});
```

If I add a hack like this after the above snippet.

```
jQuery("#LINKID a").click(function() { return false; } );
```

I can see the image being fetched but it will this stop the functionality associated with   tag

Comment: After link is clicked, image should be downloaded and only after this user should be redirected to a page from `href` attribute? That is what you mean?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
jQuery("#LINKID a").click(function(){
   var url = "Image location";

   jQuery('<img />')
   .appendTo(document.body)
   .load(function(){
        //Once the image is loaded unbind the click even handler and
        //then let the link follow its url
        jQuery("#LINKID a").unbind('click')[0].click();
   })
   .attr('src', url);
});
```

Comment: Thanks ShankarSangoli..  I tried this but it didn't work. Any thoughts for a work around

Comment: @Ron - What happens with this code? Do you see image being loaded?

Comment: The browser opened the page defined in href of anchor tags.  There was no get url request call in net tab of firebug. Will jQuery('<img />') create an anonymous image object?

Comment: Yes, it will create an image element. Try my edited answer I have added it to body element now.

Comment: Tried that.. If I add alert after the entire block.. i can see the call being fired..   I am using jQuery 1.2.6.. can this be a problem?

Comment: I think upgrading to latest version would better

Comment: Your respones is correct. The call did go through.. Had to use VRTA to check the connections made by the browser. Could not see it in net tab of firebug.

Answer (score 0):

This one works across all browsers. Had to add time stamp to the url

```
jQuery("#LINKID a").click(function() {            

var url = "Image Location";
    url += "&_=" + (+new Date());

var img = new Image();

img.onload = function() {

             window.location = jQuery(this).attr("href");

        };

   img.src = url;    

   return false;

});
```